# Image as background of each TableView for each Section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Does anyone know how to set the **background** of a table for **each section of the tableview**?

I already have the header image for each section...

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIImage *viewImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (1024, 1024)];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:viewImage];
    if (viewImage) {
        return imageView;
    } else {
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

...but I haven't seen any answers for how to change the **background of each tableview section**?

Because each tableview section needs to have a different background image just like there is a different header image for each section.

Thanks!

Comment: there is no direct way to do this. but since table view is subclass of scrollView, if you get the entire section rect, you can add a custom view to tableview's divvies as background and set it frame

Comment: remove the position of index value and add the change image in the array. after reload the tableview. but its not a good solutions

Comment: I think you need to have array of `UIImage` for Header section of tableVIew.

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala I'm not talking about the `viewForHeaderInSection` like I said, you know?

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P Not sure what this means, but sound like you think its not a good solution anyway

Comment: @SolaWing thats an interesting thought.  Which TableView method would I put that inside of though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you maybe can do this.

```
NSArray *imgArr = @[@"first.png",@"second.png",@"third.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgArr[secetion]]];
imageView.frame = .....;
return imageView;
```

Comment: Do that where?  Thanks!